# Eclipse > Egit plugin not showing *.jasper files for commit in git (bitbucket)?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

Eclipse > `Egit` plugin not showing

```
`*.jasper`
```

files for `commit on git` (bitbucket)?

Also tried `Team > Add` to Index on particular jasper files but still not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `.gitignore` file has some rule for ignoring that file/folder